# Why doesn't unlockedActions override requireAuth in CakePHP?

Tags: security, cakephp

In my Cake 2.3 app, I have an action that's called via ajax. Since I'm using the Security component, I had to use `$this->Security->unlockedActions`, otherwise the action would fail.

However, `unlockActions` doesn't work when `$this->Security->requireAuth()` is called. Is this a bug? Do I have a misunderstanding of how CakePHP handles security?

Why doesn't `unlockActions` override `requireAuth`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SecurityComponent::requireAuth()` adds that action to an array of required actions, stored in `SecurityComponent::$requireAuth`.

If you take a look at the Security Component's [startup code](http://api23.cakephp.org/view_source/security-component#l-215), you'll find that `SecurityComponent::_authRequired()`, the method that checks the `$requireAuth` array, is called *before* the unlocked actions are even checked. I imagine if you require an action to be authorized, that should take precedence over telling the app that it doesn't.

I would still consider this a bug (or incorrectly documented), as it clearly states in the documentation:

> There may be cases where you want to disable all security checks for
>   an action (ex. ajax request). You may "unlock" these actions by
>   listing them in $this->Security->unlockedActions in your beforeFilter.

This is a new feature so it might be good to open up a ticket explaining the confusion and see what the core team thinks about it.

I should also note here that disabling the Security Component for ajax requests isn't always necessary. I have several apps that successfully use the Security Component, along with CSRF checks, side-by-side with ajax.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks so much! Any chance you have a blog post or tutorial explaining how to have ajax running smoothly with Security? :)

Comment: I don't, sorry. I've actually not had much trouble doing regular requests, since the token is always `POST`ed as well. `checkAgent` is the only thing that has caused problems for me. Big helpers: get [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) and install [Firebug](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit). They'll help you immensely when it comes to debuggin ajax requests.

Comment: Ah, you're posting from a form that uses all of Cake's automagic. My problem is I'm running a JS app (via Knockout) and the JS is outputting the JSON directly... hmm.

Comment: If you're `POST`ing raw inputs then yeah you'll have definite issues with the Security component as it expects the token. Not sure where JSON becomes a problem though as it's a response, not a request. Either way if you're generating your forms with Javascript, security is going to have to be a custom implementation. If you generated the Javascript *using* a custom Cake helper that included the token logic, it could work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is very different from security.

Security protects against several ways to hack into your website, while the auth components handles the clearance of your users. When a member is updating his profile, I do want to verify that it is a logged in member (authentication), but i might not want to use the security component for the action he is calling.